# Objective C - Random Character Generator

Tags: objective-c, random, generator

im looking for some help for a random character generator. At the moment i know how to create the generator using switch and char but i would like the code to go through the awnsers yes, no and maybe and then display one of them indefinitely.

any help would be appreciated :)

P.S im using objective C on Xcode

Comment: Create an array of the characters you want (and a string can be regarded as an array for this purpose).  Randomly select elements of the array.  (Have no clue what you mean by "i would like the code to go through the awnsers yes, no and maybe...".  That doesn't parse.)

Answer (score 1):

Digits 60-95 translate to letters A-Z in an ASCII mapping. Just generate a random number in that range, cast it to a `char`, and you're done. For example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand() % 35 + 60;
char c = (char) r;

fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
NSLog(@"%c", c); 
/* etc. */
```

Comment: Ive got all of that down already, however how would i be able to go through the list and then no matter what it generates it still displays a character i choose. asif it was a default word or number

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do, sorry.

Comment: So for example, if i pressed a random button but i wanted it to go through maybe, no and yes and display that happening. but i want it to display yes every time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you just want to grab one of three characters at random.
Simply use `int r = arc4random() % 2;` to generate a random integer between 0 and 2. Then use a switch case to evaluate the three possibilities.